# Getting the first Monday after the third Friday

Tags: sql-server, date-math

I have seen on this site how to get the the third Friday of the month:

```
select quote_date
FROM table
 where  datename(weekday, quote_date) = 'Friday'
and datepart(day, quote_date)>=15 and datepart(day, quote_date)<=21;
```

How would I get the first Monday after this third Friday?

Answer (score 11):

"The first Monday after the third Friday" could be rewritten as "Three days after the third Friday."

So once you identify the third Friday (via any method), it's just a matter of adding 3 days. Something like: `DATEADD(DAY, 3, ThirdFriday)`.

This is also a great use case for a Calendar table, which you can read more about [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/), [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6848/create-a-calendar-table-in-sql-identify-date-gaps-islands/), and [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6894/create-a-calendar-table-in-sql-server-to-optimize-scheduling-problems/).

Using your original query from your question, and assuming this gives you your desired results for "third Friday", then you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT ThirdFriday                 = quote_date,
       FirstMondayAfterThirdFriday = DATEADD(DAY, 3, quote_date)
FROM table
WHERE  datename(weekday, quote_date) = 'Friday'
AND datepart(day, quote_date)>=15 
AND datepart(day, quote_date)<=21;
```

Answer (score 3):

@AMtwo 's answer has the key that you want "three days after the third Friday." I took your question to mean you'd like to alter what filters the query to the third Friday so that it filters to the next Monday rather than listing it in the SELECT clause. If so, you can be even more direct:

```
select quote_date
FROM table
 where  datename(weekday, quote_date) = 'Monday'
and datepart(day, quote_date)>=18 and datepart(day, quote_date)<=24;
```